# How to store es6 map using redux persist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I am trying to store an ES6 map using redux-persist so that my data is not lost on page refresh. This is the code I am attempting to work with

```
const initialState = {
  subevents: new Map()
};

const subEventsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.SET_SUBEVENT: {
      const subevents = state.subevents;
      subevents.set(action.subevent.key, action.subevent);
      return {
        ...state,
        subevents
      }
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const transformSubeventMap = createTransform(
  (state) => {
    return { ...state, subevents: JSON.stringify([...state]) }
  },
  (state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return { ...state, subevents: JSON.parse(new Map(state.subevents)) }
  }
);

const subevents = persistReducer(
  {
    version: 1,
    key: 'subevents',
    storage,
    transforms: [transformSubeventMap],
    whitelist: ['subevents']
  },
  subEventsReducer
);

export default subevents;
```

I would like to store the subevents property as a Map of (Date, Array). Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Is this related? https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/223

Comment: Yes, I did have a look at it, but it was not what I was looking for. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `JSON.parse(new Map(state.subevents))` you are parsing a `Map`, when you should parse a `JSON` string

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried your code but I feel like there's an error in you transformer. You may have missed to add the `subevents` property:

```js
const transformSubeventMap = createTransform(
  (state) => {
    return { ...state, subevents: JSON.stringify([...state.subevents]) }
  },
  (state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return { ...state, subevents: JSON.parse(new Map(state.subevents)) }
  }
);
```

This may not be enough though. Since `redux-persist` doesn't handle ES6 Maps, you have to convert them to array to properly save them. Also, you don't need to convert to JSON.

Try something like this:

```js
const transformSubeventMap = createTransform(
  (state) => {
    return { ...state, subevents: Array.from(state.subevents) }
  },
  (state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return { ...state, subevents: new Map(state.subevents) }
  }
);
```

You can also pass an options object with a whitelist to the transformer, making it much more simple:

```js
const transformSubeventMap = createTransform(
  subeventsMap => Array.from(subeventsMap),
  subeventsArray => new Map(subeventsArray),
  { whitelist: ['subevents'] }
);
```